# Shortcut for switching between tabs inside "Source tab" in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, browser, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Suppose you have too many tabs opened inside "Source" in chrome developer tools. How to switch among those files using a keyboard?

Comment: There's no hotkey but you can use Ctrl-O minidialog.

Comment: ok. That's the same as using Ctrl-P. Nice trick by the way.

Comment: We can use Ctrl+] to move right and Ctrl+[ to move left. Is it working for everyone?

Comment: @AmitGoel That doesn't transition between the files tho, 
it transition between the dev-tools tabs(console/elements/application/network…)